# AC to DC power supply

Tags: power, power-supply

I am trying to make an AC to DC supply to run my motors,
motors needs 12 to 24 volt and 1.6 amp current.
So i used a transformer(output 12 volt, current 1.5-1.8 amp) ,then a full wave bridge rectifier, then a capacitor(25v, 1000uF) and then this L7824 .But is not working and the ic L7824 gets very hot.
So what i do now..?

Comment: Could you add a schematic? There is a tool in the question editor. Also the MIN input voltage with that regulator is 26V.

Comment: Sir m using my mobile phone so it is not shown that option sorry

Comment: It looks like even one of your motors would likely exceed the specifications of the regulator, especially if you have not given it a large heatsink.  Do you absolutely have to regulate?   Could you consider a switching regulator which would be more efficient and turn less power into heat?  If you must stay with a linear regulator, you may need a larger part, or using external transistors.

Comment: A 12V transformer, rectifier and smoothing capacitor will only give you about 16V into the 24V regulator! You need at least 26V.

Comment: Ok sir then plz tell me which ic should i use whose input will be in range 10 to 14 volts??

Comment: Why do you need a regulator?

Comment: If you just want to power something, you might look into re-purposing a surplus PC switching power supply.  If you want to design a moderately high current linear power supply, great, but realize there's a lot to learn.  Likely you will end up with a control IC and a large frame-mounted power transistor - see for example your typical open frame linear supply from Power One or their competitors.

Comment: Here's someone who has written up how the PowerOne type supplies work: http://www.djerickson.com/p1hack/

Comment: @Leon Heller
I need regulator to get a perfect DC supply.

Comment: Why do you need a "perfect DC supply" for driving motors?

Comment: @Leon Heller
sir becoz motors work well for perfect DC supply.

Comment: They don't need it!

Comment: But sir when i not connect that regulator then capacitor gets very hot..

Comment: There is something wrong with it, then.

Comment: May be, bt i made that ckt as it is given in book

Comment: I think my english is good enough that every one can understand exept you..
So,I think you should improve your English understanding.

Comment: What I mean is that you should try to avoid using abbreviations and slang, since it's not as clear as normal english and someone might find it difficult to understand. It's a matter of etiquette more than language skills. And don't be rude to others (I don't get easily offended, others might do :)).

Answer (score 2):

"motors need 12 to 24 volt and 1.6A current"

- do they need 12 or 24 volt? Or do you want to be a able to regulate the voltage? (It is more common to PWM the power to the motor than to vary the voltage)
- is 1.6A current for all the motors together?

You say you use a 12V transformer. That will give you (at most) sqrt(2)*12V = 17V. Not enough to feed an L7824, which needs at least 24V + 2.5V = 26.5V.

If you would feed the L7824 27V and pass 1.6A through it there is ( 27 - 24 ) * 1.6 = 4.8W dissipated in the chip. That requires a reasonable heatsink.

If you would regulate that 27V down to 12V and still require 1.6A that would mean 24W dissipation. That requires a bigger heatsink (for instance one rated 2C/W ).

In practice you won't get an accurate 27V from your rectifier+capacitor, so you must dimension it to provide *at least* 27V *under all circumstances*, and then dimension your heatsink for the highest voltage it could get at its input.

But that all said, maybe you should tell us what you want to achieve, so we might be able to find a better solution.

Comment: Sir, motors can work on both 12v and 24 volt,but they work well for 12v.
My ckt till capacitor is ok, i hv made that ckt from a book..
But as i learn that it will not give pure DC, so for making it pure DC i am using L7824, but till this discussion it seems that i should use something else..

Comment: A chip ike the L7824 can only reduce the voltage. But just to to power a motor you don't need a 'nice' DC like you would need for a analog circuit. Why don't you just connect your motor(s) to the capacitor?

Comment: Your capacitor should probably be a bit higher voltage as well, maybe 35V or 40V.

Comment: You need a good capacitor here, it is going to supply your 1.6A current, so it must be rated for at least that current, the expected voltage (25V might be OK, but as rob suggests 35V is probably better), and 1000uF is too low, I would suggest 10.000uF. And the diodes must of course be rated for 2A average, 10A (ballpark estimate) peak.

Answer (score 0):

Run the motor directly off the unregulated supply. Motors don't need perfectly regulated supplies; the regulator only wastes power, limits the current to its own rating (probably 1A) which is very detrimental to the motor's starting torque, and adds failure modes such as the heating you observed, and sensitivity to high voltage spikes generated by the motor's brushes.

If the capacitor gets hot, what physical size is it, and what is its ripple current rating? I recommend using one whose ripple current rating is at least twice the motor's average current rating.

Comment: Sir, capacitor gets very hot if i not connect regulator.

Comment: Plz help me sir.

Comment: Please answer the questions!

Comment: Based on not enough information, I'll suggest the capacitor is inadequate for the job and should be replaced with one rated for at least 2 A ripple current, preferably higher. Two or more capacitors in parallel can be used if necessary.